# How do I install itpp on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 through terminal?

Tags: software-installation, gnuradio

[ITpp](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/4.3.1/) installation for Ubuntu versions 14.04 and 16.04 respectively. Can you please tell the commands for the same?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, or Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Also it may help if you're specific on what `itpp` means as I don't see a program of that name in a quick search (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&keywords=itpp)  and why is 'gnuradio` tagged, or how does it relate?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 sir